# Dovecot can't show some messages after migration

Tags: dovecot, exim, roundcube

I'm doing a migration from a shared server (old server) to AWS (new server). When I migrate all the mail, in the new server I can´t see some messages when I try to open them in roundcube. Both old and new server have exactly the same configuration (exim, dovecot, clamav, spamassassin, roundcube, mysql, etc.). I tried to see error logs but nothing is showed. However, I realized that messages that can't be shown are in binary format not in plain text. I suppose there is a configuration I am not doing or an encryption issue that I still don't know how to configure. I have to mention that files messages are not corrupted, because in the old server are showing correctly, but not in the new server. I have read a lot of documentation, but still don't find a solution.

Messages that correctly showing are this format:
[image]

While messages than showing incorrectly are this format:
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue. Those messages that were showing incorrectly were compressed in gzip format. I didn't realized before because they had not an extension. So, in dovecot config file I enabled zlib plugin and compressed messages started to show correctly. For more information check this out: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/zlib_plugin